# Losing colours when using drawInRect withAttributes [UIColor blackColor]

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode8

I've replaced a deprecated usage of drawInRect:withFont, but the side effect is that I can no longer see some of the colours in a colour bar in my app. Green is replaced with black (except with the first box in the bar, because the yearText hasn't been drawn yet), yellow and red are replaced by white.

Here's the code I use to add colour to the bar boxes:

```
CGFloat *yearColor = (CGFloat[]){0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0};
CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, yearColor);

CGRect yearRect = CGRectMake(xOffset+1,
                             yOffset+kScoreBoxHeight-2,
                             kScoreBoxWidth+50,
                             kScoreBoxHeight);
```

Here's the code I'm replacing the deprecated drawInRect with

```
[theYear   drawInRect:yearRect 
       withAttributes:@{
         NSFontAttributeName: 
           [UIFont   fontWithName:@"PFTempestaFiveCompressed" size:8.0],   
         NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor darkGrayColor ]
       }];
```

[image]

Here's the original drawInRect method using withFont. I'm not specifying any font colour, relying on the default, black.

```
[theYear drawInRect:yearRect withFont:[UIFont 
                             fontWithName:@"PFTempestaFiveCompressed" size:8.0]];
```

[image]

The problem seems to occur with dark colours (black, grey). Here's an example that works with brown.

```
[theYear drawInRect:yearRect
             withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: yearFont,
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor brownColor]}];
```

[image]

Comment: You'll need to post the source that is drawing the colored rectangles. There is not enough information in the question for anyone to answer you!

Comment: It looks like you might be relying on a side-effect of the font drawing (setting the foreground color) to color your rectangles, but impossible to tell without source.